# WinSvr2012, Exchange 2013

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

I’ve got a Server running Windows Server 2012 Standard and MS Exchange 2013.
Everything was running fine, able to access ECP and OWA no problems.

I then installed MS Exchange Service Pack 1 and noticed that the C:\ was full. The C: drive being a 500GB partition and only having WinSvr2012 and Exchange installed I thought this was a bit odd. Ran Disk cleanup on C:\ and freed up 400GB+. After the weekend I went to start creating the mailboxes but wasn’t able to access the ECP.

When trying to access ECP i get the certificate warning but then get an error message of:

> Not Found
>
> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

I then logged onto the server to see if I could access ECP from there, making sure that there was no network issues. Navigated to [https://localhost/ecp] but get the same as from my PC, (Certificate warning then error 404).

When I opened Server Manager I noticed that quite a lot of services had stopped and would not start. Services are:

- Microsoft Exchange Transport Log Search
- Microsoft Exchange RPC Client Access
- Microsoft Exchange EdgeSync
- Microsoft Exchange unified Messaging
- net.Pipe Listener Adaptor
- World Wide Web Publishing Service
- Microsoft Exchange Unified Messaging Call Router
- Net.Msmq Listener Adapter
- Microsoft Exchange Search host Controller
- Microsoft Exchange Anti-spam Update
- Net.Tcp Listener Adapter

Putting the services error aside for a moment, i went back to looking at the ECP issue. On a few forums/blogs that I’ve had a look at, other people have suggested to open IIS and check the URLs and bindings. I’ve gone to open IIS but get the below error:

> Filename: C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\ApplicationHost.config
>
> Line number: 0
>
> Root Element is missing.

I’m not sure if i have been looking in the wrong area altogether trying to start these services or whether there is a different underlying error?

Advice would be appreciated.

Note: This server is **not** in a production/live environment so some downtime of the server is possible.

Comment: Did you confirm *what* Disk Cleanup was getting rid of? Chances are, you bricked IIS and Exchange by doing this. At this point, I'd look at starting over again or trying a restore point (or backups).

Comment: @NathanC It was the Windows Disk Cleanup that I used so the standard Downloaded Porgram files, Recycle Bin Temporary Files etc... that were deleted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yup, bricked IIS and/or Exchange. Had to rebuild from the ground up.

Answer (score 1):

If your ApplicationHost.config is empty (corrupted) you can find the backup of this file under "C:\inetpub\history".